# Can I download ODBC drivers on Azure functions?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to connect to a Spark cluster via an ODBC connection from my Azure function app, so I can write a query from a database. Is there any way I can download ODBC drivers in the function app?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't installed yet? See also [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/559327c2-6bd9-4337-bfe4-5d5d8273a813/install-odbc-driver-for-sql-on-function-app-linux?forum=AzureFunctions).

Answer (score 1):

By defualt, ODBC drivers are installed as part of Azure function sandbox just like we have it in our windows machine.

[image]

Which you also will be able to see it in KUDU.

[image]

```
PS D:\Windows\SysWOW64> dir odbcad32.exe /AD
```

Please try accessing spark cluster and see if it works.

Comment: Use /s switch instead of /AD. /AD did not work in KUDU